# Node js- Access and query windows printer queue

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am developing a printer management software in nodejs. For this I need access to the printer queue, so as to log the details of the ongoing printing task. I need access to the number of copies, page size etc. Is there an equivalent of .nets System.Printing PrintQueue class in nodejs?

Tried various printer packages available but none seem to serve my purpose.